# Return ALL index positions that hold a certain value in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

New to programming, so please bear with me!
In C, say you have an array {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}. How do I return the index position of ALL the values that are 1? So in this case it would be {1, 3}. I have no trouble when I am looking for the max/min/occurrences in an array, because you can just keep an ongoing 'count' of values. However I can't get my head around this one as I don't see how the for loop works here. Here's what I've tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
   if (array[i] == 1) {
      result[i] = i;
} }
```

Where result[] is a new array (I think I need a new array since there is more than 1 output). But this only finds the first occurrence and forgets about the second.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a separate index for occurrences. If `result` needs to only hold the number of occurrences, you'll need to keep two arrays (one temporary, one for the final result) or do a first pass through `array` to find out how many occurrences or matches exist, before making a second pass to copy over indices. Here's how to do it with two arrays:

```
int occurence = 0;
int* occurrences = malloc(sizeof(int) * numValues);
for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        occurrences[occurence++] = i;
    }
}
int* result = malloc(sizeof(int) * occurence);
for (int i = 0; i < occurence; i++) {
    result[i] = occurrences[i];
}
free(occurrences);
/* do stuff with result... */
free(result);
```

You could do it in one pass by resizing the `result` array on each match via `realloc`, but that would take more time.

Comment: You can do it in one pass: allocate `result` with `result = malloc(sizeof(*result)*numValues)`, then scan the array, filling `result` from the front (there is enough space guaranteed), and finally `realloc()` the resulting array to the right size.

Comment: A `realloc` will create a second array, anyway, and just reassign the pointer.

Comment: Not necessarily. It may just as well just split the allocation into two parts, a used part, and an unused one. If it does that, it's just a change in the `malloc()` internal metadata, likely with constant complexity. Of course, `realloc()` may be implemented in a stupid way, which might indeed trigger a copy.

Answer (score 1):

As you are newer to Programming, lets make it simple.
Lets assume you are not worried about the space/memory that `result` holds.

```
int onesCount = 0; // number of 1(s) count
for (i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
   if (array[i] == 1) {
      result[onesCount] = i;
      onesCount++;
   }
}
```